# Javascript Regex for Employee Code prefix validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want a single line regex that will check that a string starts with alphanumeric characters followed by a special character `( ) -_ /`, and within these special character there can be any alphanumeric characters.

I need this kind of validation for Employee Code prefix in my system for example I want to allow these kind of string A12(6) or H3(G) or H4-C, 840D_CODE.

I am jquery validator method and currently I am using the following code :

```
$.validator.addMethod("Prefix", function(code_prefix, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||    code_prefix.match( /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\(\)\-\_\/]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/);
}, "Please specify a valid prefix");
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny he is just expecting a regex in javascript that match the string like A12(6) or H3(G) or H4-C or 840D_CODE

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one out:**

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*([( ) -_ /][A-Za-z0-9]*[( ) -_ /])
```

*Parts of the regex:*

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]* //starts with alphanumeric characters
(
[( ) -_ /] // first bracket/dash/underscore..
[A-Za-z0-9]* // another set of alphanumeric characters
[( ) -_ /] // second bracket/dash/underscore..
)
```

Comment: Your answer was not worthful for for me.
Now the correct answer is -
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\-\_\/]$/

Comment: Yes, that might be more useful for your cause. If you answer your question you can designate that as a correct answer, so the question won't pop up as unanswered. Cheers!

Comment: `was not worthful for me`Damn you don't have to be that rude, come on at least a word of thanks ...